# Error binding to object in Knockout

Tags: knockout.js, javascript

I am working on understanding Knockout. While developing I had a problem with computed variable in this scenario called total. It does not seem to update in my UI interface despite binding to the  total  variable from the UI. It also had an effect of hiding the other controls at the back of the bound total control , in this case my select drop down was hidden. Please  am I doing something wrong. this is my Javascript

```
<head><title>Hello Knockout</title></head>
<body>

    <p>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value : Listprice , valueUpdate : 'afterkeydown'" />
        <span data-bind="text : formatCurrency(Listprice)"></span>  
     <span data-bind= "text : total"/> 


     <select data-bind="options : color  , optionsText : 'name' , value:selectedColor,  optionsCaption : 'Choose item..'" />
        <span data-bind="text : selectedColor" />
```

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >

        var data = {
            "Id": 1001,
            "SalePrice": 1649.01,
            "ListPrice": 2199.00,
            "ShortDesc": "Taylor 314CE",
            "Description": "Taylor 314-CE Left-Handed Grand Auditorium Acoustic-Electric Guitar"

        };
        $(function () {
            var Colored = function (id, name) {
                this.id = ko.observable(id),
            this.name = ko.observable(name)
            };

            var vm = {
                id: ko.observable(data.Id),
                saleprice: ko.observable(data.SalePrice),
                Listprice: ko.observable(data.ListPrice),
                ShortDesc: ko.observable(data.Description),
                color: ko.observableArray([
                new Colored(1, "Black"),
                new Colored(2, "Red"),
                new Colored(3, "Blue")

                ]),
                selectedColor: ko.observable(),
                quantity: ko.observable(2)

            };

            vm.total = ko.computed(function () {
                return this.Listprice,10 ?  this.ListPrice: 0;
            }, vm);


            vm.formatCurrency = function (value) {
                return "$" + value();
            };


            ko.applyBindings(vm);

        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you always format your spans like this:

```
<span data-bind="text: total"></span>
```

rather than

```
<span data-bind= "text : total"/>
```

EDIT:

Also `Listprice` is an observable, which is a function.  Make sure you invoke it using () if you want to get the current value:

```
return this.Listprice() ?  this.Listprice(): 0;
```

Here is a working fiddle you can play with: http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/vDmP2/

Comment: thanks john. the other items appears after using your suggestion but I still have a binding problem of the computed variable. please any thoughts

Comment: Edited my answer to show how to access observables in expressions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have observed that but It seems to produce an error in chrome anytime I access it like a method. Haven't tried it on other browser though. is it possible there is a change somewhere in knockout.js v 2.1.0

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?  Try looking at the fiddle I attached.